# Adafruit I2S MEMS microphone is not working with voice activity detection system

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, microphone, pyaudio

I am trying to make a speech to text system using raspberry pi. There are many problems with VAD.  I am using DeepCpeech's VAD script. Adafruit I2S MEMS microphone accepts only 32-bit PCM audio. So I modified the script to record 32-bit audio and then convert it to 16 bit for DeepSpeech's processing. Frames generation and conversation parts are below:

```
for frame in frames:
    if frame is not None:
        if spinner: spinner.start()
        #Get frame generated by PyAudio and Webrtcvad
        dp_frame = np.frombuffer(frame, np.int32)
        #Covert to 16-bit PCM
        dp_frame=(dp_frame>>16).astype(np.int16)
        #Convert speech to text
        stream_context.feedAudioContent(dp_frame)
```

PyAudio configs are:

```
'format': paInt32,
'channels': 1,
'rate': 16000,
```

When VAD is starting it is always generating non-empty frames even if there is no voice around. But When I am setting a timer for every 5 seconds it shows that the recording was done successfully. I think the problem is that the energy(voltage) adds some noise and that's why the microphone can not detect silence and end frame generation. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for DeepCpeech's VAD script and found it. The problem is connected with the webrtcvad. The webrtcvad VAD only accepts 16-bit mono PCM audio, sampled at 8000, 16000, 32000 or 48000 Hz. So you need to convert the 32-bit frame to 16-bit (I am about PyAudio output frame) to process webrtcvad.is_speech(). I changed and it worked fine.